# Проблема с квадратными скобками ([]) в xpath

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Есть такой небольшой кусок кода с использованием `domDocument` и `xpath`.

При использовании `xpath query` оно преоброзует квадратные скобки в какие то символы.

Как обойти это?

Вот сам код.

```
<?php    
    $str = '<ul class="top"><li><a href="[T]XX[/T]">Testing</a></li></ul>';
    $str = '<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>'.$str;
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($str);

    $xpath_menu_bottom = new DomXpath($dom);

    $x = $xpath_menu_bottom->query('(//ul[@class="top"])[1]')->item(0);

    var_dump($dom->saveHTML($x));
?>
```

Comment: закодировали :) - `var_dump(urldecode ($dom->saveHTML($x)));`

Comment: @splash58 Точно спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо раскодировать закодированное значение:

```
$htmlEncoded = $dom->saveHTML($x);
$htmlDecoded = urldecode($htmlEncoded);
var_dump($htmlDecoded);
```

Результат ДО (`$htmlEncoded`):

```
<ul class="top"><li><a href="%5BT%5DXX%5B/T%5D">Testing</a></li></ul>
```

Результат ПОСЛЕ (`$htmlDecoded`):

```
<ul class="top"><li><a href="[T]XX[/T]">Testing</a></li></ul>
```